# How to search for files by size and extension ?

Tags: command-line, find, search

I want to delete all empty files with a particular extension from a directory and all its subdirectories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following, to confirm upon deleting each file first:

```
$ find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*.txt" -empty -ok rm {} \;
```

or if you feel more confident:

```
$ find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*.txt" -empty -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: On newer versions of `find` the `-delete` option will be simpler.

Comment: keep in mind NOT to do this on the /dev directory

Answer (score 6):

Usually, the answer to “how do I … in a directory and its subdirectories” involves `find`. Use `-type f` to match regular files, `-name '*.ext'` to restrict to a particular extension, and `-size 0` to restrict to empty files.

```
find /some/dir -name '*.ext' -type f -size 0 -exec rm {} +
```

If your version of `find` is too old, you may need '… -exec rm {} \;' instead (using `+` is faster because it calls `rm` on many files at once). Under Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD and OSX, you can use `find`'s build-in `-delete` action and the `-empty` predicate (equivalent to `-size 0` on regular files):

```
find /some/dir -name '*.ext' -type f -empty -delete
```

In zsh, you can use the `**` glob to recurse into subdirectories and [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to restrict the matches to regular files (`.`), of size 0 (`L0`).

```
rm /some/dir/**/*.ext(.L0)
```